# Wire heating from microwave signal

Tags: heat, thermal, microwave

How would one calculate the temperature change in a wire into which a microwave signal of a given frequency and power is applied?

Comment: by the DC resistance rise and voltage rise from T rise due to skin effect and conductivity drop for power and conductor impedance

Comment: So I should calculate the effective resistance from the skin effect? Does 'conductivity drop' refer to increased resistance due to temperature increase? Could you elaborate please? I'm familiar with calculating this with DC but not with RF AC.

Comment: you also need the thermal resistance to ambient, amount of power that actually makes it into the wire (some RF power will reflect). In the real world there are so many things going on (many unknowns) that probably the only practical way to get an estimate is to use an EM simulator like HFSS or CST.

Comment: A wire is no longer "just" a wire at microwave but rather an inductor with some stray capacitance and DCR and insulation.  But then you just use a piece of wire about 1/4\$\lambda\$for an antenna

Comment: By now you ought to know Conductivity is inverse of REsistivity and Wiki is your friend

Comment: When you say power, is that the power being transmitted or the power being lost in the wire?

Comment: Its the power transmitted. I have a wire loop to which I apply 1W through a matching network. I now need to estimate the rise in temperature, but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

For a wire loop, use appropriate fine gauge Litz wire for lower inductance, lower skin effects or   copper tubing for heat conduction in W/'C.

With the appropriate wavelength in copper tubing you can make into an induction heater. Or if you want it cool with lower losses, use Litz wire.

Your problem-statement is ill-defined and more complex than in comments.  There are electromagnetic and thermodynamic equations.